# Discord.js channel is undifined when getting it with ID

Tags: discord.js

```js
const other_channel_id = 913189654247907380;
const other_channel = interaction.guild.channels.cache.get(other_channel_id.toString());
```

For some reason the other_channel is undifined.

I try to use it in a InteractionCreate event, if there is something special about that.

The channel is a voice channel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript does not handle big numbers that well, which is why even with `.toString()`, it didn't turn into what you wanted. Change the `Number` into a `String` directly and it should work

```js
const other_channel_id = "913189654247907380";
const other_channel = interaction.guild.channels.cache.get(other_channel_id)
```

Take a look at what JavaScript turns the ID into (more specifically the ending digits):

```js
console.log(913189654247907380)
console.log("String version: " + (913189654247907380).toString())
```